# How to process all available datagrams before continuing in libuv

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, libuv

I have a graphics/network loop, as shown in pseudo-code below:

```
while (window.isOpen() || uv_run(uv_default_loop(), UV_RUN_NOWAIT)) {
    update_network();
    update_simulation();
    render_vsync();
    // blocks to maintain ~60Hz
}
```

This is fine, but my `uv_run` only processes one single `uv_udp_recv_cb` per invocation. This means that I am limited to receiving 60 datagrams per second due to my blocking rendering loop.

I am sending over 60 small datagrams per second to my loop causing a backlog and my loop suddenly can not keep up.

**Q:** How can I get libuv's `uv_run` to process all data held within the kernel before continuing - i.e. have it process all buffered or available datagrams in a single call until there are none left to be `recv`?

I could do this to clear the backlog and process more per iteration, but if there aren't enough packets then I am wasting cycles searching for non-existant datagrams and am still limiting myself to 600 datagrams/second.

```
while (window.isOpen()) {
    // process up to 10 datagrams per loop
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        uv_run(uv_default_loop(), UV_RUN_NOWAIT);
    }
    update_network();
    update_simulation();
    render_vsync();
    // blocks to maintain ~60Hz
}
```

Is there any other fast alternative to get it to process *all available* datagrams until the next loop or to figuring out how many datagrams are currently available for reading?

I need to avoid functions that are only available on specific operating systems and would much prefer something either within libuv or cross-platform at the very least.